# ANDROID : Share session between Webview and httpclient

Tags: android, webview, httpclient, session-cookies

I have actually a logged session in my WebView.
But I use also httpclient to send and get data from the web. I saw on the internet that it's impossible to get the content of a WebView, so I needed to use my httpclient to get data from a webservice.

The problem is that this webservice uses sessions... and my session is in my WebView, so the httpclient doesn't have it and I can't access the content of the webservice.

I see many posts about this problem but I didn't understand the solution.

Here is what i did on my onPageStarted :

```
CookieManager mgr = CookieManager.getInstance();
Log.i( "URL", url );
Log.i("Cookie",mgr.getCookie("mywebsite.com"));
String cookie_string = mgr.getCookie("mywebsite.com");
if(cookie_string.length() > 1) {                    
    Data.instance().getPref().edit().putString("cookie",cookie_string).commit();
}
```

I saw that I have this kind of things, so I hope those include session too:
(i remove the number)

```
__utma=......(number)......; 

__utmc=number;

__utmz=number.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); 

wt3_eid=%number%number; 

wt3_sid=%number
```

Then i don't know what to do in order to set this cookie in my httpclient. I try that, with no success :

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
BasicCookieStore cookieStore = new BasicCookieStore();
String login_cookie_string = Data.instance().getPref().getString("cookie", "");
String[] cookie_parts = null;
if(login_cookie_string.length()> 0)
{

    //debug_view.setText(login_cookie_string);
    Log.d("COOKIE", login_cookie_string);
    cookie_parts = login_cookie_string.split(";");

    for(int t=0;t < cookie_parts.length;t++)
    {
        String[] cookieContent = cookie_parts[t].split("=");
        Cookie login_cookie = new BasicClientCookie(cookieContent[0],cookieContent[1]);
        ((BasicClientCookie) login_cookie).setDomain("mywebsite.com");
        cookieStore.addCookie(login_cookie);
    }

}
((AbstractHttpClient) client).setCookieStore(cookieStore);
```

Comment: Route the traffic through a proxy like WebScarab or Fiddler for finding out the remaining differences between WebView and httpclient requests.

Answer (score 15):

So , this is what I did and it worked for me -

```
HttpRequestBase request = new HttpGet(uri);
request.addHeader("Cookie", getCookieFromAppCookieManager(uri.toString()));
```

Now the implmentation for the getCookieFromAppCookieManager is as follows -
The method gets the cookies for a given URL from the application CookieManager. The application CookieManager manages the cookies used by an application's WebView instances.

```
@param url the URL for which the cookies are requested
@return value the cookies as a string, using the format of the 'Cookie' HTTP request header
@throws MalformedURLException


public static String getCookieFromAppCookieManager(String url) throws MalformedURLException {
    CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
    if (cookieManager == null)
        return null;
    String rawCookieHeader = null;
    URL parsedURL = new URL(url);

    // Extract Set-Cookie header value from Android app CookieManager for this URL
    rawCookieHeader = cookieManager.getCookie(parsedURL.getHost());
    if (rawCookieHeader == null)
        return null;
    return rawCookieHeader;
}
```

Comment: works well for me if all you want is to share a webview cookie with native code (i.e. httpclient)

Comment: I can not get back the sessionid cookie. Why?

Comment: if you use https, than you find this useful: rawCookieHeader = cookieManager.getCookie("https://" + parsedURL.getHost()); and working!

Answer (score 10):

Follow this tuto (archived):

http://web.archive.org/web/20120615042447/https://metatroid.com/article/Android:%20handling%20web%20service%20authentication

Here the content of the webpage:

> Something you might find yourself doing in Android is web
> authentication.  Most web sites issue a cookie to track session ID's
> and keep a user logged in. In order to maintain this authentication,
> you will need to keep cookies synced between activities and between
> http clients and webviews.
>
> The method I ended up doing, which seems to work well enough, was to
> create a class that extends Application, then define a single
> HttpClient to be used throughout the rest of the Application. That
> code looks like:
>
> ```
> public class AppSettings extends Application {
>     private static final DefaultHttpClient client = createClient();
>
>     @Override
>     public void onCreate(){
>     }
>
>   static DefaultHttpClient getClient(){
>           return client;
>   }
>   private static DefaultHttpClient createClient(){
>           BasicHttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
>           SchemeRegistry schemeRegistry = new SchemeRegistry();
>           schemeRegistry.register(new Scheme("http", PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 80));
>           final SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = SSLSocketFactory.getSocketFactory();
>           schemeRegistry.register(new Scheme("https", sslSocketFactory, 443));
>           ClientConnectionManager cm = new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(params, schemeRegistry);
>           DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(cm, params);
>           httpclient.getCookieStore().getCookies();
>           return httpclient;
>   }
> ```
>
> This class also creates an HttpClient that is suitable for AsyncTasks
> and making multiple simultaneous http requests. Using
> ThreadSafeClientConnManager for the ClientConnectionManager let's you
> run http requests inside AsyncTasks without causing a force close when
> you press the back button and start a second, or third.
>
> It also creates a single default cookie store that can be accessed in
> all your activities. You would use this in your other activities by
> calling the getClient() method.
>
> For example
>
> ```
> public class SomeActivity extends Activity {
>       static DefaultHttpClient mClient = AppSettings.getClient();
>       ...
>       try {
>   
>           HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet('URL');
>           HttpResponse response;
>           response = mClient.execute(httpget);
>           ...
>       }
>       ...
>     }
> ```
>
> If you find it necessary to use a webview and need it to access and
> use the same cookies as your client. You can sync the client's cookie
> store using CookieManager: (in onPageStarted method)
>
> ```
> DefaultHttpClient mClient = AppSettings.getClient();
>
>
> Cookie sessionInfo;
> List<Cookie> cookies = mClient.getCookieStore().getCookies();
>
> if (! cookies.isEmpty()){
>       CookieSyncManager.createInstance(getApplicationContext());
>       CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
>   
>       for(Cookie cookie : cookies){
>               sessionInfo = cookie;
>               String cookieString = sessionInfo.getName() + "=" + sessionInfo.getValue() + "; domain=" + sessionInfo.getDomain();
>               cookieManager.setCookie("example.com", cookieString);
>               CookieSyncManager.getInstance().sync();
>       }
> }
> ```
>
> You will need to switch example.com with the correct domain.