# Keep session between Android WebView's loadUrl

Tags: android, session, cookies, webview

There have been a couple of question's about syncing cookies, but none of the solutions described, seem to work for me.

I've got one webView in my Android app. The first time I show it, I use a HTTP POST to log the user in, and the server shows the homepage. Als long as I stay in this webview, the session is retained. But as soon as I do a new loadUrl on the webview, apparanetly the session is lost, and the server wants me to log in again.

I've tried [android-share-session-between-webview-and-httpclient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11224454/android-share-session-between-webview-and-httpclient). It doesn't seem to work, in my onPageStarted the list of cookies is always empty.

I've also tried to start syncing cookies before the initial loadURL (with POST) of the webView:

```
CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance(); 
cookieManager.setAcceptCookie(true);

CookieSyncManager.createInstance(getBaseContext());
CookieSyncManager.getInstance().startSync();
```

and then in onPageFinished:

```
CookieSyncManager.getInstance().sync();
```

This doesn't work either, so now I really don't know what to do. Does anyone have experience with this and can explain to me how to do it?

Comment: Tried this. This worked for me perfectly?
http://stackoverflow.com/a/17629754/1467204