# Android WebView - how to keep the user inside the app when they click on WebView links?

Tags: android, android-webview

I had this command to keep the user still inside the app after they clicked links inside a webview. But I lost it and cannot seem to find what it is.

Could anyone please remind me what that command is?
Thank you!

This is my code:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    WebView webview = new WebView(this);
    webview.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(false);
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webview.setInitialScale(1);
    webview.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);

    webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    });

    WebSettings webSettings = webview.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    webSettings.setAllowContentAccess(true);
    webSettings.setEnableSmoothTransition(true);
    webSettings.setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
    webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webSettings.setSupportZoom(true);
    webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);

    setContentView(webview);
    webview.loadUrl("http://www.stitcher.com/podcast/entrepreneuronfirecom/entrepreneur-on-fire-tim-ferriss-other-incredible-entrepreneurs");
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To capture all clicks within the webView, you need to set a custom WebViewClient with `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` set to `true`

```
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
});
```

Without doing this, it will open in the browser.

[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldOverrideUrlLoading(android.webkit.WebView, java.lang.String)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldOverrideUrlLoading%28android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String%29)

> Give the host application a chance to take over the control when a new url is about to be loaded in the current WebView. If WebViewClient is not provided, by default WebView will ask Activity Manager to choose the proper handler for the url.

Comment: Thank you - trying it now. Also, for some reason, I thought there was also a 1-line fix for this, no?

Comment: Just so we are on the same page, I am going to update my original question with my latest code.

Comment: I just updated my original question with my current code. Could you please take a glace at it to just make sure I am not veering off track somewhere. I am a bit new with WebView on Android. Thank you!

Comment: Seems fine to me. I'm not aware of any 1-line way to do this, other than putting all the above code in 1 line, which would look messy. :)

Comment: it seemed to have worked on the emulator. Now I'll test on device - thank you!

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
WebView webView = findViewById(R.id.idname);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.loadUrl("urlname");
```