# Android webview keep user logged in

Tags: android, webview

I am developing an android application. It is a simple application containing a webview which will load my mvc website.

First page of my application is login page.Once user logs in to the system application page is shown.

Requirement - Is it possible for webview to remember the credentials and allow the auto log in to system when he/she visits next time?

need help. Following is main activity code.

```
            public class MainActivity extends Activity {
            WebView webView;
            String loginUrl = "mail.xyzabcd.com";

            @Override
            public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            // Adds Progress bar Support
            this.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
            requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
            webView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
            WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
            settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
            settings.setLightTouchEnabled(true);
            settings.setSupportZoom(true);
            settings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
            webView.loadUrl(loginUrl);

            // on clicking a link load it in the same link
            webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {              
            }
            });
            }
```

Comment: This worked perfectly for me.
http://stackoverflow.com/a/17629754/1467204

Answer (score 0):

**Web View** is just a widget which is used to display. It cannot by itself remember data across sessions (if the activity is killed).

What you could do though is to create a resource file that would store the user id and password (based in the logic you want) and then have the **Web View** check to see if this resource file is present. If present, you could extract details from there. You could do your own encryption as well to secure the data.

Comment: thanks Sunil for your quick response. Can we use cookies? At the time of search I came accross settings.setSaveFormData(true),  settings.setSavePassword(true) can we do something like this?

Comment: Yes, you can use the CookieManager and CookieSyncManager to store such data. The CookieSyncManager serves to synchronize cookies between RAM and persistent storage.