# WebView Blank Screen Only With Mobile Sites

Tags: android

I am a beginner Android developer and have an issue with WebView. My application runs in my Main Activity. When a TextView is clicked, it opens a new activity that is a WebView.

When I use the phone’s back button to back out of the WebView to get back to the Main Activity, it displays a blank screen before getting completely out of the webview activity. I also see this same blank screen very briefly after leaving the Main Activity and before the website initially starts to load.

The interesting thing is this only happens when the target website is optimized for mobile, for example, en.m.wikipedia.org, Non-mobile sites back out to the Main Activity without this extra blank screen.

I’ve done a lot of research and cannot find anything unique to opening mobile URLs. The blank screen fixes I have found do not eliminate it in my application. Any insight would be appreciated.

activity_web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

WebActivity.java

```
public class WebActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_web);

        // Receive URL from the Main Activity
        // I’m pretty sure this is not done right, but it still passes the URL. Research how to do it right.
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null){
         String theURL = extras.getString(null);
         }

    WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);

    webView.loadUrl(theURL);

    }
}
```

Comment: Does it happen with **all** mobile websites ? Have you tried changing the User agent of the WebView to desktop one ?

Comment: As far as my testing can tell, yes all mobile sites. I did try changing the User agent as recommended in another thread, but no difference. This is not a show stopper, but It's also not "clean".

Comment: I just found 2 mobile sites it doesn't happen on. I will now be focusing on it being related to https sites. Up til now all the mobile sites I hit were all https. I just replicated it on a bare bones test app I just built. Just a button calling the WebView activity and hard coding urls.

Comment: You might try overriding the back button to immediately exit your activity, with `finish()`, instead of going back in the WebView. This will avoid the white screen when the activity with WebView is exited.

Comment: Finally figured it out. [Stay in app](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17629754/4667867). My WebView was staying in the app for non-https urls but going to the external browser for https urls. I didn't notice it until I changed the size of the WebView, then it was obvious. That jump to external was the blank screen. Staying in app for both resolved it.