# Get Session from Android Webview

Tags: android, session, webview

I have created an Android application, in that I want to get Session from webview.

How to make it possible ?

Thanks.

Comment: post what you've tried till now; did you try CookieManager.getInstance()?

Comment: @AhmadAlsanie, tried this method but it gives cookie data, I stores my items in Session, so how to get session data in webview?

Comment: Do you need it for log in purposes ?

Comment: No, actually my site is for online shopping with limited fixed price items and I stores cart in session, so for checkout I use Paypal for web and I want to implement inapp purchase for android app, so I need cart from session in Android.

Comment: okay walk me through the process of creating your session (Do you use HTTPURLConnection) ? other details about the code would be beneficial

Answer (score 0):

I use this method for getting session cookies from a webview:

```
public static String getCookieFromAppCookieManager(String url) throws MalformedURLException {

   CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
   if (cookieManager == null)
        return null;
    String rawCookieHeader = null;
    URL parsedURL = new URL(url);
    rawCookieHeader = cookieManager.getCookie(parsedURL.getHost());
    if (rawCookieHeader == null)
        return null;
    return rawCookieHeader;
}
```

Comment: what do you know ? I use this in production code. And I tested a lot of other ways like XWalkCookieManager etc. Maybe this snippet came from stackoverflow, so what ? @Kay U a purist?

Comment: @Kay Yes, you are completely right mr. perfectionist.

Comment: @Decoy, Thanks for answer, this is working for getting cookies, but i stores some data in session, so how to get it.

Answer (score -1):

There are two ways:

- If a developer has made a httpclient, and makes an api auth call and store the cookie. Then you sync the httpclient's cookie with webview and maintain a session natively.
- If user has used a webview to make an auth call and the cookie resides in the webview.

First one is your code and simply making a getter will return instance of DefaultHTTPClient. The instance will have access to cookies too. you can make async calls to auth api to get correct cookie in the instance. Make sure to keep HttpClient and Webview in [sync](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1652850/android-webview-cookie-problem).

For retrieving cookie in second method, you would use CookieManager object and the url which user is logged into and you need cookie for, example twitter.com See the second post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11224454/android-share-session-between-webview-and-httpclient) for implementation details.